Is Entity Relationship Diagram (ERD) available for Delta Live Tables in Databricks?
I am trying to use ERD for my code but i am not able to, can someone help me. Thanks in advance. For instance -
CREATE TEMPORARY STREAMING LIVE VIEW cust_silver
COMMENT 'CUSTOMER DATA SILVER'
AS
SELECT cust_id, cust_name, cust_dob, cust_address, BadpDatetime
from STREAM(`pool`.`details`.`customer_database`);

CREATE OR REFRESH STREAMING LIVE TABLE dimension_customers (
  junk_key_cust BIGINT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
  cust_id LONG,
  cust_name STRING,
  cust_dob DATE,
  cust_address STRING,
  BadpDatetime TIMESTAMP
);

APPLY CHANGES INTO
  live.dimension_customers
FROM
  STREAM(LIVE.cust_silver)
KEYS
  (cust_id)
SEQUENCE BY
  BadpDatetime
STORED AS
  SCD TYPE 1;

I tried to add it at dimesnion_customers level - cust_id LONG NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
but I am getting this error "Please change the column nullability and retry".

I have tried your code. it is working fine. try from the beginning once deleting all tables.
